# How to hide columns in a tables ? BootStrap in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

When i develop a Html table with static content .

Is there any work around How to apply BootStrap functionality to the table ? HIDE some columns for when the table is accessed from other devices ?

I am new to this framework which is really looks cool and better responsiveness .

I heard things like Bootstrap functionality can be easily applied to table just by using the CSS , is THAT TRUE ?

If so I dont know how it will make flexible just after applying css .

First look at my post itself it will be confusing becoz i am confused totally .

Regards

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4

Comment: i had css & js of bootstrap and i dont know how to apply to my html table and on which element to apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bootstrap specific thing. It sound like you would need to set an id or class for the column(s) (TD tags in the table) you want to hide then use jQuery to say if there is a different device (mobile I assume) then hide the class or id.

You can see an example of this code [at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6LX/)

Hope this can get you started. Entire code is on the JS fiddle link

```
        var isMobile = { Android: function() {
```